# How to specify a different value for a node parameter, part of a node group, for different materials

Tags: mesh, materials, node-editor, shaders

I've got this object which exists of 10 meshes or so. Their UV maps are all different, of course. I would like to have the same shading on all of them, so I created a node group. The node group includes the normal map. I wish to resize the normal map. For that the [Mapping Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/types/vector/mapping.html) can be used. The mapping node is also part of the node group. What I would like to be able to do is, reuse this node group entirely, and be able to set a different scale, on a single axis, per instance of the node group (or per material is you will).

[image]

Comment: Current GSOC has a project about it (see https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/User:OmarSquircleArt/GSoC2019/Proposal and a work in progress version can be downloaded here https://blender.community/c/graphicall/gdbbbc/ this is 'cycles procedural branch'). But for now, you'll need to recode (with nodes) the vector mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question, do you mean you want to duplicate the node group to different materials? ctrl+c and then ctrl+v in new material's node editor would work but I think you have to enable the "copy attribute" add-on